# What is the right place to use "I got it working" and "I made it worked" and "It's working"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I had a situation where I struggled to make my program run. So after a great struggle **I got it working**. Is this the correct statement I can use here? Or is there any other sentence like **I made it work** ? I got confused. Is there any other sentence that suits this situation?

Comment: How about *Hard-earned?*

Comment: Just FYI, those sentences aren't grammatical anyway. "I got it work-`ing`" or "I made it `work`". My exclamation in this case however is usually "YES!, Finally! *sigh*"

Comment: Related: [“Work” vs. “working” (noun)](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96769/43980), [“It's working for me”: correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/51733/43980)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close, but no cigar!

The correct phrase to use is ***I got it working*** or ***I got it to work***.

Also, at the beginning of your question, "I got a situation" should be ***I had a situation***.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Moore is correct, but if you want to use "made" instead of "got" you could say "I made it work". Also, since you are talking about a computer program, you could say "run" instead of "work" (work isn't wrong, but run seems more specific) or even "I debugged it".